# Core Data Many To Many Relations

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, core-data, entity-relationship

i have a problem with iOS Core Data and many to many relations.
I want to write a fitness application. So i need three tables.
Following constuct:

**Table Workout:**

- id
- name

**Table Practice:**

- id
- name

**Table Set**

- id
- break

Now, each workout can have many practices. And each practice can be in different workouts.
Also each practice can have many sets. And each set can have exactly one practice. But (and now comes the important part) a practice can have different numbers of sets in different workouts.

So a set relates to a practice and a workout, or?

I don't know how i have to design my erd.
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`each practice can be in different workouts` and `a practice can have different numbers of sets in different workouts` can not both be true at the same time.

So, you need some other entity to deal with that. Something like a `WorkoutPractice`. Instances of `WorkoutPractice` would not be reusable.

So a workout has many workout practices. Each workout practices has only one workout. Each workout practice has one practice. Each workout practice has a group of sets. Practice no longer has sets.

Comment: I hope i understand what you wrote :) Do you mean something like that: [link](https://nopaste.me/view/eeb644c2)

Comment: I created a erd. [Image](http://i.imgur.com/o3LtCOs.png). Is that correct? And does a practice has multiple WorkoutPractices?

Comment: Yes, it's much easier to draw as an entity diagram that an a table rows example but yes, you appear to understand correctly. And yes, a practice would have multiple workout practices.

Comment: Thank you a lot. You saved my day :)

Comment: No problem, and welcome to SO. Remember to vote and tick answers that help and solve ;-)